# Problem with connecting to LDAP server with StartTLS by Spring LDAP

Tags: java, spring-boot, ldap, spring-ldap, starttls

I have got problem with connection to LDAP server with StartTLS by Spring LDAP.

Configuration of Spring LDAP:

```
<bean id="startTlsContextAuthenticationStrategy"
          class="org.springframework.ldap.core.support.ExternalTlsDirContextAuthenticationStrategy">
        <property name="shutdownTlsGracefully" value="true"/>
</bean>

<ldap:context-source id="ldapCtxSource"
                         url="ldap://xxx.xxx.pl:389"
                         base="ou=xxxxxx,ou=xxxxx,o=xxx,dc=xx"
                         anonymous-read-only="true"
                         username="xxx"
                         password="xxx"
                         authentication-strategy-ref="startTlsContextAuthenticationStrategy"
                         native-pooling="false"
    />

<ldap:ldap-template id="ldapTemplate" context-source-ref="ldapCtxSource"/>
```

As you can see I'm using a ExternalTlsDirContextAuthenticationStrategy and it extends AbstractTlsDirContextAuthenticationStrategy. It has processContextAfterCreation method which is dedicated for StartTls operations but when I debugging in this method I can see that it is not ivoked.

When I call any method of template eg: `ldapTemplate.search("", "(objectclass=person)", (AttributesMapper) attrs -> attrs.get("cn").get());` it gives me followin exception:

```
javax.naming.AuthenticationNotSupportedException: [LDAP: error code 13 - TLS confidentiality required]
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(LdapCtx.java:3146) ~[na:na]
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:3101) ~[na:na]
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2892) ~[na:na]
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.searchAux(LdapCtx.java:1846) ~[na:na]
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_search(LdapCtx.java:1769) ~[na:na]
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_search(ComponentDirContext.java:392) ~[na:na]
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.search(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:358) ~[na:na]
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.search(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:341) ~[na:na]
    at java.naming/javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.search(InitialDirContext.java:296) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate$4.executeSearch(LdapTemplate.java:322) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:363) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:328) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:604) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:594) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:482) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:498) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:514) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
```

Additional information: I tried to connect to this server without Spring LDAP, basing on processContextAfterCreation method described above, and it works fine:

```
Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<>();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "xxx");

String keyStore = "pathToJKSFile";
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", keyStore);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "xxx");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", keyStore);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "xxx");

LdapContext ctx = null;
StartTlsResponse tls = null;

try {

    ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);

    tls = (StartTlsResponse) ctx.extendedOperation(new StartTlsRequest());
    tls.negotiate();

    SearchControls searchControls = new SearchControls();
    searchControls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);

    String ldapSearchBase = "xxx";
    String searchFilter = "(uid=*)";

    NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> results = ctx.search(ldapSearchBase, searchFilter, searchControls);

    while (results.hasMoreElements()) {
        LOG.info(results.next().toString());
    }

} catch (javax.naming.AuthenticationException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (tls != null) {
        try {
            tls.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if (ctx != null) {
        try {
            ctx.close();
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```